# C - how to return more than one char

Tags: c, function, pointers, return

Anyone know how to return 3 char values from a function to the main part? The three chars have to be input by the user and made into a pyramid. I have been told to use pointers but don't understand how to do it and keep getting errors. These 3 characters then have to be used in the main function to make a pyramid shape.

Comment: Perhaps you want a *string*? Then the best solution is to pass in an array as an argument to the function, and let the function fill in the array properly. This works even if you just want three separate characters, and not a string. Either that, or return a *structure*.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on my comment, there are basically two ways I would recommend solving this problem, of which the first comes in two variants (depending on use-case and requirements).

1. Pass an array as argument to the function, and have it filled in. This comes with two variants depending on what is needed:

   - Just use an ordinary array

     ```
     void doSomething(char *array)
     {
         array[0] = 'A';
         array[1] = 'B';
         array[2] = 'C';
     }
     ```

     Call like

     ```
     char array[3];
     doSomething(array);
     printf("First character is '%c'\n", array[0]);
     ```
   - The second variant is basically the same as above, but treats the array as a (null-terminated) string:

     ```
     void doSomething(char *array)
     {
         strcpy(array, "ABC");
     }
     ```

     Call like

     ```
     char array[4];  // One extra for terminator
     doSomething(array);
     printf("String is '%s'\n", array);
     ```
2. The second way to return multiple values is through the use of structures:

   ```
   struct Data
   {
       char a;
       char b;
       char c;
   };

   struct Data doSomething(void)
   {
       struct Data data;
       data.a = 'A';
       data.b = 'B';
       data.c = 'C';

       // or struct Data data = { 'A', 'B', 'C' };

       return data;
   }
   ```

   Call like

   ```
   struct Data data = doSomething();
   printf("First character is '%c'\n", data.a);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I write an example of pointers, I hope it's useful:

```
main(){
    int a,b,c;
    doSomething(&a,&b,&c);
}

void doSomething(int *x, int *y, int *z){
    //example
    *x = 5;
    *y = 7;
    *z = 10;
}
```